# VSCode windows symbol servers project.json

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, symbols

I'm trying to debug my windows project with vscode. The code is c++ and I'd like to have the windows pdb files from the symbol server on hand for the debugger but I'm not sure how to do it. I read in another thread something about adding build options to a project.json file but I'm not having any luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the thread that you are referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350170/visual-studio-code-not-loading-symbols-on-os-x